# How to get bounding box info of intersection box in forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

After adding intersection box for sectional viewing of model using sectional analysis tool, is it possible to get its bounding box information?

---

1. original model

[image]

---

2. intersect box view whose bounding box needs to be extracted

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can access the geometry info of the section box via `sectionExtension.tool`:

```
const sb = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Section')
sb.tool.getSectionBoxValues() 
//sectionBox: (6) [-2.8294310569763184, -6.648449420928955, -9.332106590270996, -0.0652092695236206, -1.3873761892318726, -3.4865833520889282]
//sectionBoxTransform: (16) [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```