# Restore sectionBox in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

[How to get bounding box info of intersection box in forge viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738766/how-to-get-bounding-box-info-of-intersection-box-in-forge-viewer)
i want to restore section extension box bounding value to be restored.for that for below method i get box value.
**getSelectionbox**

now i want to restore that to viewer/set that saved value to viewer for that is there any method is available?

i used **setSectionBox(box)** but it isn't worked for me.

Thank you

Here is code sample:

```
viewer.restoreState(currentState, null, false);

                viewer.hide(Object.values(val.hiddenNodes));
                if(Object.values(val.isolateNodes).length > 0){                     
                    viewer.isolate(Object.values(val.isolateNodes));
                }
                if(val.cutPlanes.length !== 0){
                    viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Section").then(function(sectionTool){
                        sectionTool.activate(val.sectionStyle);
                        
                        
                        var sectionTool = markupsExt.tool.getSectionBoxValues();

                        const sectionbboxmin = new THREE.Vector3(val.sectionBox[0], val.sectionBox[1], val.sectionBox[2]);      
                        const sectionbboxmax = new THREE.Vector3(val.sectionBox[3], val.sectionBox[4], val.sectionBox[5]);
                        const box = new THREE.Box3(sectionbboxmin,sectionbboxmax);
                        box.transform = val.sectionBoxTransform;
                        sectionTool.setSectionBox(box);
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried applying a custom section box to a model in Forge Viewer using this code snippet:

```js
let box = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(-100,-100,-100), new THREE.Vector3(100,100,100));
let sectionExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Section');
sectionExt.setSectionBox(box);
```

And the result is this:
[image]

So this seems to be working ok. Could you provide more details about how you tried to set the section box?

### EDIT:

Here's how you can restore the section box from a list of cutplanes (like the one you can obtain from `viewer.getState()`):

```js
function restoreSectionBox(viewer, cutplanes) {
    let box = new THREE.Box3();
    for (const cutplane of cutplanes) {
        const normal = new THREE.Vector3(cutplane[0], cutplane[1], cutplane[2]);
        const offset = cutplane[3];
        const pointOnPlane = normal.negate().multiplyScalar(offset);
        box.expandByPoint(pointOnPlane);
    }
    const sectionExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Section');
    sectionExt.setSectionBox(box);
}

// ...

let cutplanes = [
    [1, 0, 0, 40],
    [0, 1, 0, 50],
    [0, 0, 1, 30],
    [-1, 0, 0, 60],
    [0, -1, 0, 20],
    [0, 0, -1, 70]
];
restoreSectionBox(viewer, cutplanes);
```

Comment: What should i do is loadMode -> select element -> right click -> select as section box.
now getState of the model from that i get(viewport,cutplanes) and also store sectionbox value.
then restore that state using restoreState(storeViewport) and setSectionBox.
but i got as output was with bounding box but in differ in size as well as differ in cutplanes.

Comment: In that case there might be some issue with how you're computing the bounding box from the cut planes. Can you include that code in your question as well?

Comment: I have added my code snippet in question for that i used to restore state and restore section box.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're taking the `val.cutPlanes`, `val.sectionStyle`, `val.sectionBox` values from. But I've updated my answer with a code that can restore the section box from the list of cutplanes that can be obtained with `viewer.getState()`.

Comment: val.cutPlanes, val.sectionStyle, val.sectionBox this value are store in db.